# What are the submodules of $M⊗K$?

Tags: modules, tensor-products, extension-field

Let $k$ be a field and $K$ is a extension of this field.

And let $A$ be a finite type $k$-algebra, and $M$ be a finitely generated module over $A$.

Then, is the form of submodules of $M⊗_kK$ always $N⊗_kK$?
(where $N$ is an $A$-submodule of $M$)

Comment: Do you want $A$-submodules or $A\otimes K$-submodules ?

Comment: sorry,as A⊗K submodule .

Answer (score 1):

No.  Small examples suffice: take $k=\mathbb{F}_p$, the finite field of $p$ elements, and take $K=\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.  Now, take $A=k$ and $M=k^2$.  Then $M$ only has $p+1$ non-trivial submodules, while $M\otimes_k K$ (which is isomorphic to $K^2$) has $p^2+1$ non-trivial submodules.  Thus $M\otimes_k K$ must have submodules which are not of the form $N\otimes_k K$, with $N$ a submodule of $M$.

Comment: oh thank you for the nice counterexample!